# Mongodb Aggregation get Data per user

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Report table sample data

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("614415f4a6566a001623b622"),
    "record" : [ 
        {
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-09-17T04:13:39.465Z"),
            "status" : "time-in",
            "month" : 9,
            "day" : 17,
            "year" : 2021,
            "time" : 1631852019465.0,
            "date" : ISODate("2021-09-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        },
        {
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-09-17T04:14:01.182Z"),
            "status" : "time-out",
            "month" : 9,
            "day" : 17,
            "year" : 2021,
            "time" : 1631852041182.0,
            "date" : ISODate("2021-09-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        }
    ],
    "uid" : ObjectId("614415b0a6566a001623b80b"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-09-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "status" : "time-out",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-17T04:13:40.102Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-09-17T04:14:01.831Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Users table sample data

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("615c0f6db30aff375cd05ac1"),
"displayName" : "test test",
"firstName" : "test",
"lastName" : "test",
"email" : "test@gmail.com",
"brand" : "Jollibee",
"phone" : "+632312312312312",
"role" : 1,
"isVerified" : true,
"isArchived" : false,
"createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-05T08:40:13.208Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-05T08:40:13.208Z"),
"__v" : 0
```

}

I have a data like this

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { brand: "Jollibee" } 
    },
    {
          $lookup: {
              from: "orders",
              let: { id: 'id' },
              pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        date: { $gte: ISODate("2020-11-01"), $lt: ISODate("2021-11-31") },
                    }
                }
              ],
              as: "orders",
          },

    },
    {
      $project: {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "orders": 1
      }

    }
  ])
```

when I'm using this aggregation I'm getting all the data inserted per user.

[image]

What I want to happen is that. I will only get the data that belong to the user and not all the data of all users.

Added the sample documents for each collection

Comment: Can you share sample documents for both collections? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun hello edited the question. sorry for the missing sample documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing the userIds of both collections. You should add that on your $match. [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Se1MPzUHJjo)

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      brand: "Jollibee"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            date: {
              $gte: ISODate("2020-11-01"),
              $lt: ISODate("2021-11-30")
            },
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$uid",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "orders",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "orders": 1
    }
  }
])
```